# How to post an open graph action to many user timeline?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-opengraph

My website has a queue script which executed by cronjob command line. It calculate a logic for many users. When that calculation is true for each user, it should post an action to that user timeline (those users already authenticated and we have user fb id). How I can do that? Currently, with the current user that browsing the website, I can post action by using

`$fb->api('/me/'.....`

How to post an open graph action to other users timeline?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to post on any users profile you have to use $fb->api("$user/feed") ; and you have to make the batch request if you want to post on more than one user.